# manipulations with SU(N) Nekrasov partition function

Tags: representation-theory, partition-function, instantons

Think of a Young tableau $R$ as collection of rows
$y_1 \geq ... \geq y_d > y_{d+1}=0$ and all others zero,
with $\ell(Y):= \sum_j y_j$
and for a box $s=(i,j)\in R$ we have
$a_Y(s):=y_i-j$ and
$l_Y(s):=y_j^D-i$,
where $y^D_j$ corresponds to the transpose $R^D$ of $R$.

How do we prove that
$$
Z_k=\sum_{\ell_1+\ell_2=k} \prod_{i,j} \prod_{(s,s')\in R_i\times R_j}
\frac{1}{1-\alpha_i \alpha_j^{-1} t_1^{-l_{R_j}(s)} t_2^{1+a_{R_i}(s)}}
\frac{1}{1-\alpha_i \alpha_j^{-1} t_1^{1+l_{R_i}(s')} t_2^{-a_{R_j}(s')}}
$$
(where the sum means sum over all Young tableaux $R_1R_2$such that
$\ell(R_1)+\ell(R_2)=k$)
can be expanded, in the limit $t_1t_2=1$,
and after defining $t_i:=e^{i2\epsilon_i}$,
$\alpha_i:=e^{i2a_i}$,
$\epsilon:=\epsilon_1$ as
$$ Z_k = \sum_{\ell_1+\ell_2=k} \prod_{(i,m)\neq(j,n)}
\frac{\sinh (a_i-a_j +\epsilon(y_{i,n}-y_{j,m}+m-n))}
{\sinh (a_i-a_j +\epsilon(m-n))}$$
where $y_{i,n}$ denotes the $n$-th row length of diargam $Y_i$

What I've been able to do: reduce it to proving the following.
Define $f_R(q)=\sum_{i=1}^d \sum_{k=1}^{\mu_i} q^{k-i}$,
$\sum_kC_k(R_1,R_2)q^k=(q+q^{-1}-2)f_{R_1}(q)f_{R_2}(q)+f_{R_1}(q)+f_{R_2}(q)$,
and $2a=a_1-a_2$.
Then I need to prove that
$$
\prod_k \frac1{(\sinh 2a +\epsilon k)^{C_k(R_1,R_2^t)}}=
\prod_{s\in R_1}\prod_{s'\in R_2}
\frac1{\sinh 2a -\epsilon(l_{R_2}(s)+1+a_{R_1}(s))}
\frac1{\sinh 2a+\epsilon(1+l_{R_1}(s')-a_{R_2}(s'))}
$$

Refs:

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0310235

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0206161

http://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/transp/masterthesis.pdf eqs 4.82,83,84

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306238 section 3.1

The book *Symmetric functions* by Macdonald could be useful

Comment: Hi @jj_p. Consider adding references and links in order to receive useful and focused answers.

Comment: The original computation was done by Nekrasov himself, while the statement above is contained eg in Tachikawa's master thesis

Comment: Hm, perhaps you could show some effort, even if it's unsuccessful, to try and prove it for yourself first?

Comment: Crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1126283/11127